# What would happen if all female humans on earth died?

Tags: population

Say if all the female humans were infected by a disease and all of them die, as this disease affects only female.

Even if some male gives birth to a female child, it will die as environment on Earth is affected all over and the disease is present.

How long will humans as race will exist on Earth under this condition. What all measures we can take to continue the human race.

Comment: Males *don't* give birth to children. Only females can make new lives. Since all females are dead, there will be no new children, ever. The human species will go extinct in few decades when the last lonely man dies.

Comment: @AlexP at the risk of sounding pedantic, only females can *gestate* new life, but they can't create it by themselves. Both Male and Females are needed to *create* new life. Sure, you could argue that IVF and frozen sperm changes that, but ultimately that sperm was created by a male.

Comment: @AlexP Some transgender men can, [and have](https://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/31/health/trans-man-pregnancy-dad-trnd/index.html). Just saying.

Comment: @TimBII: Actually, as they say, what you need is one woman and 15 minutes of a man's time...

Comment: @F1Krazy He was Biologically female though, so he would have died in this scenario.

Comment: @F1Krazy It's fairly clear that, in this question, "male" and "female" are referring to biology, not gender identity. While it would be an interesting sci-fi scenario to devise a disease which affects people based on their gender identity rather than their biology, there is no evidence that the OP wishes to do so.

Comment: @TimBII It is actually possible  to have female female offspring using techniques pretty similar to IVF (take one egg, remove the nucleus and inject into other egg). It just isn't allowed yet.

Comment: While it is possible for women to have children without men, (sperm bank, cloneing) the reverse is not true....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No females means no more natural reproduction.

There might be some frozen eggs available here and there that could be used for in vitro fecundation, but since we lack any proved technology for artificial womb, also this path would be a dead end.

With no newborns humanity would last as the last of the males: about 80 years at best, surely less if you take into account that modern levels of assistance cannot be granted in a world of progressively lower population.

Answer (score 3):

With the future of the human race at stake, the ethical issues surrounding human cloning will vanish rather rapidly.  Direct clones of males will occur rather rapidly.

Beyond that, the answer really depends on the specifics of the disease.  When you push a species to the limits, the *precise* way the pushing occurs becomes important, down to the tiniest apparently insignificant detail.  You literally could not fill a question with too many such details.

For example, can we create females that live in a plastic bubble?  Can we create females that live for 9 months in a plastic bubble?  Can we create female organs that grow to puberty without a female body?  If you see where I'm going, any ability to create viable eggs would be of tremendous value in terms of maintaining biological diversity.

If you face an opponent that 99.99999999% kills you, what matters is not the 99.99999999%.  It's the flavor of the 0.000000001% mistake they made which really matters.   You build your counter upon that.

Answer (score 1):

They already are developing tech to create eggs and embryos from other cells in the body. See [Cloning](https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/954585/scientists-embryo-egg-sperm-stem-cell-research-cloning)

Every effort would be put into developing artificial wombs and cloning tech because the only other option would be death of the species.

This makes the assumption that humanity doesn't try to wipe itself out with each side blaming the other for the disease.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is already research into creating eggs from just sperm and sperm from eggs. It would simply accelerate this research until it was practical. And with regards to our extinction, it would likely be available to the public in a couple of decades, so there would be initial panic, and then us men would be much more productive without women around to bother us (/s)

After we get artificial birthing down, we will just continue on as a race.

Answer (score -1):

200+ years.

If we take an assumption that somewhere, a man has frozen human eggs that can be unthawed (current records are 15 years but lets pretend we could get hundreds if necessary) and used to generate new human life. We would have to utilize the womb of a cow or sow, but we have a reasonable chance of getting one to come to term and the baby surviving given modern human technology. Now, to make human life last the longest, we have to entrust the babies to the youngest humans that survive once all women are dead. This means they need to be raised and taught how to use embryos and implant them into wombs and all the necessary stuff. If we consider the human lifespan to be 84 years for men, that means he won't need to start the process until he is sixty. Assuming he was only 1ish when all females died, that gives us 83 years with him. Now to give the next generation of humans the best chance of survival, he want to raise them until they are 24, since thats about the time the brain fully develops. That means the first 24 years of the new generations lives will be spent overlapped with his. That means they will only gain 60 additional years  on top of the original 86. Now we're at 146. So now lets assume our first subject can teach the process to the new generation. This means the new generation can also create a generation of humans. With our last estimate, thats an extra 60 years, bringing the total to 204 years. Unfortunately, the knowledge to maintain the labs and equipment will be lost, and two generations is about the best we can hope for. But if our second artificial generation manages to live longer than average, we can get something like 230 extra years for the human race.

(I'm running on the assumption that we don't manage to crack cloning before the smart people die, but with proper funding we may manage it.)