# all human females except one is dead, how screwed is humanity?

Tags: humans, female, mass-death

inspired by [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125492/what-would-happen-if-all-female-humans-on-earth-died) and this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/227554/99-9-of-the-flight-capable-birds-died-at-once-how-screwed-is-the-rest-of-the-w). I'm wondering how screwed is humanity if the event like y: the last man is happening, but this time, it's the reverse.

so by that context :

- by asb will, all human female is dead.
- the female is anyone who have xx chromosome
- this also impacted close relatives of human like some species of primates.
- drawing from the comic y : the last man, the last female is living in her apartment in new york with her pet monkey
- the event, like the comic is taking place in 2002.

how screwed is humanity ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135281/discussion-on-question-by-faddllz-all-human-females-except-one-is-dead-how-scre).

Answer (score 4):

### Doctors save humanity using eggs preserved from fertility clinics

Q: *"all human females except one is dead, how screwed is humanity?"*

I wonder how *screwed* this one remaining lady and her pet monkey will be.. anyway jokes aside, this will be a huge challenge for medical science, on the short term !

She and her monkey will have to be *saved* first :)

Then, means should be developed a.s.a.p. to

- facilitate a complete, finished pregnancy outside the womb
- gather available egg cells and a bunch of *serious* male volunteers
- have these egg cells fertilized and planted into the first machine
- produce hundreds more of these machines and distribute them all over the world
- wait 9 months and hope for a relevant number of female kids
- meanwhile, proceed 10-20 years doing this on a *massive* scale

.. and hope for the best. Say, development succeeds and distribution can start after 5 years,

**harsh times will follow**

Humanity will survive, but social problems explode. Widespread depression will kick in, psychologically as well as economically. Women will be missed, not only as friends, wives and daughters, but also as a workforce. With no females, society will enter a huge crisis. And there won't be enough of these machines, to cover demand. Wars could be fought over that. In a few decades, world wide problems with men reaching old age, without being replaced by a fresh workforce. This is already the case in many rich countries now, but the effect of *zero* human procreation lasting more than 5 years will be devastating.

**It will take a century to recover from this blow**

In the first century, the "male survivor generations" will die out and world population will be drastically reduced. Women will be rare. At first, they will be considered as a *strategic asset* and kept isolated, for their safety.

Male-female relationships must be redeveloped, after 4-6 generations of machine-aided procreation. Culture will drastically change. Everywhere in the world, you'll get completely wiped out populations. Especially in countries, where modern medical science remains unavailable, the machines cannot be manned by expert personnel needed and the population will die out. In a century, more females will be around (they will be visible again) and society as we know it will slowly recover.

Comment: I suspect that you are badly underestimating the recovery time. The destruction of society could prevent any technology from helping recover. Also, what would happen if that one woman was in the Congo jungle and can't be found instead of being in western society? 10,000 years might be more realistic if science can't help.

Comment: if artificial wombs were that easy we would have them already.

Comment: @DavidR changed my title.. it is a primary condition for my answer to work: many egg cells would be preserved in fertility clinics, one woman alone can't save humanity https://www.google.com/search?q=fertitility+clinic

Comment: @John it would be a major project, especially the earlier stages, but the basis for it exists https://www.bbc.com/news/av/health-50056405

Comment: @Goodies "within ten years" is a very loaded phrase in science, we have been ten years away from fusion power plants for more than a generation.

Comment: @John I wouldn't underestimate the effect of 1) acute urgency and 2) available funds

Comment: @Goodies I wouldn't overestimate it either.

Comment: Artificial wombs probably aren't a necessity, see my comments on Alexandra Williams answer, there's five of them, a probable alternative to artificial wombs is detailed across them 

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all ovum save this sole female's are MIA? Humanity is screwed, permanently. Even if our numbers recover, which I doubt, you face major hurdles. Allow me to explain.

## First

**Genetic bottleneck.** It happened to [cheetahs](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/article/cheetahs-brink-extinction-again/). Check under subtitle "Cheetah Genes Today". And they weren't reduced to 1 female. If we have a proverbial Eve-Event? Humanity, the species, will at best be so inbred that we'll mutate into something else entirely.

## Second

**Wars being fought.** If there is 1 woman on the planet. With the majority of heterosexual men remaining? Which of these heterosexual men will not fight over her? Realistically? Gay and bi men? Asexual men? They'll be fine for the most part. Heterosexual men?

We have incels ready to kill over perceived slights of women now. Add only one in existence? Forget everything else, this alone will end humanity.

## Third

You have two real options for this woman, assuming she's even capable of getting pregnant, let alone bringing the pregnancy to term.

- She has the pick of the litter and lives like a queen for the rest of her life.
- She is a slave, a uterus with a personality they really don't want to deal with.

Realistically, 'humanity' (read: men) will not care for her autonomy. We have debates *now* about a woman's autonomy. With 50% of the global population being women. We are debating if a woman has the right to an abortion, if she has the right to self-determine if she will get pregnant or not.

With one woman on the planet? No, there is no reality in which I can imagine she'd be given any rights in regard to her bodily autonomy.

Let's paint a picture. Say this woman is 13 years old. She has her first period. So it can be assumed she can get pregnant. And no one is going to suggest impregnating her right now? *No one*?

"Humanity itself is at stake! Who cares if she isn't old enough to consent! Do you want our species to die out?!"

Another picture? She's a lesbian. Wants nothing to do with men. She is now surrounded by (give or take) 3 billion men that (as a general rule, can be assumed) want to impregnate her, with or without her consent. How long before she gets so depressed she becomes suicidal?

Or another! She doesn't want children. She hates the idea of pregnancy, despises her periods. Even if we assume we're not dealing with a trans man or non-binary person. Being a woman does not automatically equate to wanting to be pregnant. Will she be given that choice? No, she will not. She'll be gaslit, told she's selfish and killing humanity and will be solely responsible for the death of their species.

## Conclusion

Even if we assume the genetic bottleneck doesn't irreparably destroy us. Even if we assume humanity won't destroy itself over the ensuing war. **And** even if we allow for a fertile woman capable of bringing multiple pregnancies to term.

There will be no victors here. Only tragedy, and no one will listen to reason about what's best.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135330/discussion-on-answer-by-alexandra-williams-all-human-females-except-one-is-dead).